# How to eliminate elements of a vector according to a pattern

Tags: r

I have this vector:

```
a <- c("es1", "es2", "es3", "is1", "is2", "is3")
```

and i would like to eliminate all elements staring with "es", so it ends up looking like this:

```
b <- c("is1", "is2", "is3")
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Only if its starts with es, or contain es? Because from your example it could be both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove all words that contain "es", try

```
b <- a[-grep("es", a)]
```

If you want to remove only the words that **starts** with "es", try

```
b <- a[-grep("\\bes\\w+", a)]
```

Comment: Or, for the *start* condition, use `a[-grep("^es", a)]`. The caret matches the beginning of expressions.